# How to make the second half of a script run in background and periodically?

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting

I am implementing a script to automate a test procedure.
The first phase involves running like 30 tests and the second phase in this is to monitor the results and the email the final results to everyone.

In the script I need to run the second phase in the background as the tests run for hours.
So, basically after the script completes phase 1 and enters phase 2, it should then run PERIODICALLY(every 60seconds) in the background and check the status of all tests, once there is a result for all tests then it should exit.

I was looking into 'watch' command but I dont know if there is a way to exit that command from a script.
Can I have some more suggestions for this that I should look into.

Comment: Just use a `while sleep 60; do echo "Periodically"; done` loop.

Comment: Have you considered using a continuous integration tool such as Jenkins, GoCD, Travis, etc. to handle running tests, showing intermediate results, and sending emails to the team?

Comment: @xxfelixxx thanks for suggesting the tools, I need to get done with the first version soon. I shall probably look into those when I revise for the next version.
Thank you!

Comment: @thatotherguy As simple that suggestion is, I think that would be perfect. I can simply invoke phase 2 as a new file and run it using & which will put it in background and while time.sleep(60): will run it every 60 seconds.

Thanks !!